# PDF for one-dimensional data

Tags: data, distributions

Consider a dataset `data={{x1},{x2},{x3},...}`. How to generate a distribution function over $x$ using it?

I tried to construct something like PDF[data,x], however it does not work. It seems that I do not understand that the PDF in Mathematica is.

Comment: Did you search `FindDistribution` ?

Comment: Also `EmpiricalDistribution`. It really depends on what you want.

Comment: posting some of your data would help us help you

Comment: `data` is not one dimensional. `{{x1},{x2},{x3},...}` has two dimensions; try `data[[1,1]]`.  See `Flatten`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following data

```
data = {48, 56, 50, 42, 49, 57, 53, 49, 51, 49, 49, 50, 50, 47, 47, 
   50, 54, 43, 59, 54, 46, 53, 51, 43, 58, 47, 47, 46, 49, 52, 52, 59,
    48, 43, 53, 45, 50, 50, 48, 46, 54, 47, 45, 49, 52, 48, 48, 46, 
   52, 51, 61, 49, 50, 40, 53, 51, 39, 46, 47, 50} // N
```

A histogram shows a bell shaped density.

[image]

We can use the FindDistribution function to infer the two best fitting distributions.

```
In[54]:= dist = FindDistribution[data, 2,  "BIC"]   

Out[54]= {{NormalDistribution[49.572, 4.78454], -5.90009}, {MixtureDistribution[{0.630102, 0.369898}, 
{NormalDistribution[49.0805, 2.69959], 
    UniformDistribution[{39.4058, 61.4009}]}], -5.84688}}
```

We can see how the best fitting normal distribution mirrors the histogram.

[image]